# Software to convert MHT (MHTML) files to browser - and platform - neutral single-file file format

Tags: html, document-converter, archiving, file-converter

I discovered today that Firefox 57.0.4 no longer is able, even via add-ons, to display MHT files (confirmed Google Chrome doesn't either ... I don't know if it ever did).  https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1192784?fpa=1 implies that this functionality degradation is/was by planned design.

Is there some software that can convert an existing .mht file, stored on disk, from that format to some other format that will load into all web browsers on both Linux and Windows systems without requiring browser extensions?

The file format needs to be a single file, not a link to a "index.html" file on disk that points to files living in subfolders. That is what I thought the "web archive" was supposed to provide.

The software that does the converting does not have to be platform-neutral, but it has to be zero cost (meaning download and run, not download+compile+run, not pay X USD + download + run).  Ubuntu-specific and Windows-specific is ok.

However, the resulting file format should just render completely in the browser without requiring the user to download additional software.

Answer (score 2):

The suitable format for your requirement will be PDF. You shall convert MHTML to PDF and this can be opened across all the machines, where the PDF will open in the default viewer of the browsers. You may convert MHTML to PDF by using Syncfusion HTML to PDF converter, more details are discussed in the below link.

https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/pdf/html-to-pdf

UG: https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-document-conversions#mhtml-to-pdf

The whole suite of controls is available for free (commercial applications also) through the [community license](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify (less than 1 million US Dollars in revenue). The community license is the full product with no limitations or watermarks.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: I did say "zero cost".  I should have also said "without tricky economic constraints".

Comment: Can you elaborate on the community license program.  I'm not seeing a reference to it on the web pages cited.

Comment: Get more details about the community license from the below link. https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense